# What is this and is it dangerous?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]
Is this some type of moth, it looks dangerous is it?
I have only seen something like this once before.
Thank you for any information you can give me.

Comment: Where did you find this insect?

Comment: Black and red, probably dangerous! In case you don't know for sure, don't play with it.

Comment: better to say which region / country and what kind of habitat you found that.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [wheel bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug) (*Arilus cristatus*), a species of assassin bug named for the wheel-shaped projection on their thorax. They tend to prey on pest insects, but they *do* "bite" humans with their proboscis. The result is an *extremely* painful, itchy welt, though non-venomous.

These one's don't attack unprovoked, however, so generally just when trying to handle them. You should handle them with gloves.